# Lilypond function to interpolate two notes

Tags: scheme, typesetting, lilypond

I want to define a Lilypond function that will interpolate two notes.  The function should take as inputs: the first note, the last note, the step (in semitones), and whether flats or sharps should be used.

For example:

```
\sequence a g 1 sharp
```

should create the chromatic scale:

```
a ais b c cis d dis e f fis g
```

Similarly,

```
\sequence f a -2 flat
```

should create the sequence descending by whole tones:

```
f ees des b a
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any Scheme code? If you aren't quite sure where to start, [this official tutorial](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/extending/scheme-tutorial) and [these tutorials](http://lilypondblog.org/category/using-lilypond/advanced/scheme-tutorials/) might help.